# How to handle mutliple responses using Promise.all if one promise fails?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, es6-promise

Trying to combine response either (success or failure) both scenario with below code its returning empty object because one of the handler has an error.

1- How to combine responses using Promise.all if one promise fails i want to 
   have that promise error part of final response?

2- what would be right approach to have this problem resolved.

main.ts

```
private async execute(@Request() request: ExpressRequest): Promise < any > {
        let _combineData: any = [];
        const accountBalanceRequest = request.body.getAccountBalanceRequest;
        try {
            const _data1 = await this.Handler1(accountBalanceRequest);
            const _data2 = await this.Handler2(request);
            const combinedResponses = await Promise.all([_data1,_data2].map((callback) => callback(val))
                .then(values => {
                    combineData = values;
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                }); _
            }
            catch (err) {
                return err;
            }
            return _combineData;
        }
```

thats how i wanted to build the response

```
details: [{
            success response from first promise handler
        }, {
            error from 2n d promise handler
        }]
```

Comment: That `.catch()` is a good idea already, but you should `return` the error in the format that you want instead of just logging it.

Comment: WTH are those `_combineData` and `combineData`? Doesn't `combinedResponses` suffice?

Comment: @Bergi just consolidating response from promise.all